# Horde battles in Master Orders?

Tags: super-smash-bros-4

How do I beat horde battles easily in Master Orders? Specifically the harder difficulties like intense and very hard

Answer (score 1):

Custom fighters can help a lot. Put on a KO heal item, and some additional defense, and you're good to go.

Make sure you pick a fighter with a bit of knockback and range on its aerial and tilt [attacks](http://www.ssbwiki.com/Attack).

Answer (score 0):

One strategy that I use that circulated a while back is to have these 3 traits:

- Fast Hitter
- KO Healer
- Start with Bat

It makes horde battles a bit easier, and you recover from them as well.